# Is it possible to search all bash histories

Tags: bash

If you have 10 xterms open, say, is it possible to search all the bash histories combined in some way?

I  can do

```
history|grep something
```

on each one separately but I would sometimes like to avoid that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to assume these xterm windows are all for the same userid, and are all on the same host.  If they are not all the same user, then you must change their history file locations to use the same history file.  If you need to do this, see this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/760830/how-do-i-change-the-bash-history-file-location

But the main problem you will have is that bash only writes its history to `.bash_history` when the shell is closed.  However, you can edit your `.bashrc` to write the most recent command to `.bash_history` immeditately, like so:

```
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting i
shopt -s histappend

# After each command, append to the history file and reread it
export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

See this link for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows

Comment: Why export? Newly-spawned shells will re-read the bash config files anyway, and the processes you spawn from bash don't need to know what your bash settings are.

Comment: Thank you. Yes all the xterm windows are all for the same userid, and are all on the same host

Comment: @PSkocik Read the comment above the export command again.  Its not about the bash config files, its about getting the most recent history.

Comment: What I'm saying is "lose the `export`". It's unecessary and it needlessly pollutes the environment of the programs you run from the shell.

Comment: @PSkocik Oh, I agree with you, but this is part of the solution OP wanted.  OP wants to dynamically (I assume) search the history of all 10 xterm windows at the same time.  Doing this for a single window would be stupid.

Comment: Cool. I'm not bashing your answer. I was one of the first people to upvote it, actually (sometimes I wish that were visible).

Comment: Yeah man, I couldnt agree with that more.  Let me hover over the upvote button to see a list of peeps that upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

Bash has in-memory history and a history file (`$HISTFILE`, `~/.bash_history` by default). By default, all your bash sessions share one history file which gets by the in-memory history of the last exiting bash shell whenever a bash shell exits.

You can change the behavior from overwriting to appending with:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

And you can manually invoke this dumping with

```
history -a #-a stands for append
```

What I do is I have `history -a` as part of my `PROMPT_COMMAND` so that each new prompt line adds a new record in the global history file.

Then, whenever I need the history from other sessions, I just load the global history file into the in-memory history with:

```
history -r
```

> -r        read the history file and append the contents to the history

The manual of the `history` command can be read with `help history` and more details regarding history are in `man 1 bash`.

Apart from setting `shopt -s histappend` and adding `history -a` to your `PROMPT_COMMAND`, it's also useful to set sizes (HISTFILESIZE, HISTSIZE) to some large values and `HISTCONTROL`, e.g. to `"ignoreboth:erasedups"` to eliminate duplicates.

Also, I find `Ctrl-R` to be a much more comfortable way of searching through history.